# wifi antenna issue signal amp 10 dbi antenna

Tags: signal, wifi, antenna

I am running a dlink 2100ap with a (30dBm) 1W signal amp to a 10 dbi antenna. I am having issues picking up the signal on my laptop, could it be possible that the amp is making the antenna broadcast at a higher frequency? (it operates in the 2.4 Ghz spectrum up to 2.5). How far should my antenna reach?

Comment: That isn't a good idea. It may be illegal in many countries.

Comment: WiFi connectivity is not only about sending with (more) power, it is also about receiving the (smaller) signal from the client/laptop.

Comment: it is for a large manor, the tx power of the laptops wifi card should be sufficient enough right? Also the dlink 2100 ap only uses one antenna, so the tx and rx signals should be broadcasted through the one antenna.

Answer (score 1):

The amplifier doesn't change the frequency, just the power.

1 W + 10 dBi means in the directions the antenna transmits best, a receiver will see the same power as a 10 W ideal transmitter broadcasting omnidirectionally.

Comment: Hi Brian, 

Thanks for the info.

It is a hidden network with a passkey, I dont think it will arouse much suspicion, will it? if so I can swap it out with a friend and downgrade.

So the laptop should have no problem picking up the wifi signal with that configuration though?